# Editing text documents before feeding database

Tags: python, sql, text-processing, microsoft-access

I hope this is the correct section for my question.

I need to paste 30 text files (they all have the same format, like 30 characters for the first column, 15 for the second one, and so on) one under the other and create just one text file, but each file has to be filtered in a different way (for example, if in the first file it says id=1002, delete that row). Which would you think would be the better way to do that? Each file has 20k rows, approximately.

We use the Microsoft package (Excel, Access, etc.) . The unified text file is going to feed an Access file.

What do you think would be better? Create the filters in the same Access, use a VBA script (or Python/C would have a much better efficiency?) or other program like SQL Developer? Any ideas would be helpful

Thanks

Edit: I'm looking for recommendations about the software, not how to use it

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), best approaches etc. If you're looking for software, please make that clear (to avoid having your question closed) – and consult [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) (price limit? OS=Windows?)

Comment: Hello izzy. I'm just looking for recommendations about the software, and why to choose one or the other. Thanks!

Comment: @Izzy do you know where can I ask this question? I really need help with the program election, so I can start programming

Comment: I don't know where you could ask it the way it's currently phrased. Here you could e.g. rephrase it to ask for a piece of software to accomplish the task, following the advice in the "what is required" link from my previous comment. We recommend software that can achieve your purpose – we don't give recommendations on "[A vs B](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/185)" or "[Can I use X for this](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2816/185)".